# remove th tag with jquery where class

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to remove th tag with jquery where class ?

my table :

```
<table>
<thead>
<th class="NoRemove">1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th class="NoRemove">3</th>
<th class="NoRemove">4</th>
<th class="NoRemove">5</th>
<th>6</th>
<th>7</th>
</thead>
</table>
```

demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgt33/)

Scenario :

```
if(th.class!="NoRemove")
{
th.remove();
}
```

I need to write the above code to jQuery. But I have no idea how to write it

Comment: Use the `.not()` or `:not()` jQuery methods for this task.

Answer (score 1):

```
//dom ready handler - wait the execution of the passed function till the dom is loaded
jQuery(function(){
    //fetch all the th elements which does not have the class NoRemove and remove it
    $('th:not(.NoRemove)').remove()
})
```

Refer:

- [Dom Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
- [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)
- [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
- [class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)
- [Learn jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/229FS/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$(function(){
    $('table th').filter(':not(.NoRemove)').remove();
});
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/aviVeyUW/8/edit)

However, there are thousands of different ways to go about it! That's why jQuery is so awesome.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cgt33/5/)

```
$('table th:not(".NoRemove")').remove();
```